# Error using array in puppet function Each

Tags: loops, each, puppet

I'm trying to do a loop in puppet, I put this code in manifests/site.pp

```
class ubuntu_fw {
        ufw::allow { "allow-ssh-from-all":
          port => 22,
        }

        $trustips = ["1.1.1.1", "2.2.2.2"]

        $trustips.each |$trustip| {
                ufw::allow { "allow-all-from-trusted-$trustip":
                        from => $trustip,
                }
        }
}
```

But i get this error

> "Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at '.';
>   expected '}' at /opt/puppet/manifests/site.pp:13"

Using puppet 3.4.3

Comment: Seems like this version of puppet doesn't support loops (details [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399922/are-there-iterators-and-loops-in-puppet)).

Comment: You'd want to be using the `future` parser (https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3.8/reference/experiments_future.html) in order to take advantage of loops and other more advanced DSL features.

Comment: Thanks Evgeny!

Enabling future works.

Answer (score 0):

As Evgeny said, loops, iteration and the like are available in Puppet 4. (New features documented here: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/4.0.0/function.html)

You can either make the major bump to 4.0 or enable the Future parser in Puppet > 3.7.3 to get a simulation of the newer syntax.

You can do this with the following:

- Add `--parser future` to the cli when running puppet apply or puppet agent -t
- Add `parser = future` to the `main` config section of `puppet.conf`

You can make the `puppet.conf` change with the following Puppet code

```
augeas { 'puppet.conf':
  context => '/files/etc/puppet/puppet.conf',
  changes => [
    'set main/parser future',
  ],
}
```